# Unable to connect to Vagrant Apache on one computer

Tags: apache, vagrant

I have a project that includes a vagrant dev box, that works great on two (win7) computers at the office. However when I try it at home (win8.1) I can't connect to apache from the host.

Here's the blow by blow:

- The project, including vagrantfile and apache config is stored in git
- the VM boots fine, with no errors, I have tried reloading, and restarting the host
- SSH to the VM works fine
- shared folders between VM and host work
- VM box is chef/centos-6.5
- VM selinux is set to permissive
- sudo service iptables status says firewall is disabled
- disabling windows firewall does not fix the issue
- a wget on the VM to itself gets the expected response
- I normally use the address mydomain.127.0.0.1.xip.io:65000 to connect, but 127.0.0.1:65000 doesn't work either
- the failure to get to webpage is quick (< 2s), and is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in chrome
- on my work pc I can telnet to port 65000, but at home I get connection refused

reload output:

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin\vagrant.exe reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'chef/centos-6.5' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 65000 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 4.3.12 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => F:/Work/sites/4.0
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I am leaning towards it being something to do with the host, as the VM/apache config should be identical with it coming via git; but I am at a complete loss as to what it could be.

**Update - Extra Detail:** 
Running curl from windows host :

```
$ curl -Iv --connect-timeout 10 http://127.0.0.1:65000/robots.txt
* STATE: INIT =CONNECT handle 0x60002e1b0; line 1028 (connection #-5000)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* STATE: CONNECT =WAITCONNECT handle 0x60002e1b0; line 1076 (connection #0)
* Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

Disabling windows firewall, does not fix the issue.

And from the the VM it works :

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ time curl -Iv http://127.0.0.1/robots.txt
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 02 Aug 2014 16:26:29 GMT
Date: Sat, 02 Aug 2014 16:26:29 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
< Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 16:20:14 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 16:20:14 GMT
< ETag: "3f-278-4ff1b10953009"
ETag: "3f-278-4ff1b10953009"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 632
Content-Length: 632
< Connection: close
Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

IP tables

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.


vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables -L Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
destination
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st, check if the port 80 is correctly binded by apache, run the following within the VM to confirm.

`netstat -nap | grep :80`

Check if any iptables rules are in place
`iptables -L`

2nd, if you have Cygwin on Windows, run the following and see what you get. I reckon Windows firewall may be playing dirty ;-D

`curl -Is http://127.0.0.1:65000`

If you don't want to troubleshoot further and just want the service to be accessible from the host, an easy workaround may be to add a 2nd NIC (network interface) using bridge mode (public network in Vagrant) and do a `vagrant reload`. Once it is up, `vagrant ssh` into it and get the IP address (should be in the same network as the host). You should be able to access the service by using PUBLIC_IP:PORT

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have added the output of the commands to my OP. The extra network connection worked, so +1 for that but I would  prefer to know why this one computer is different to the others, seems to tarnish the point of vagrant if one has to make config changes to accommodate 1 in 3 hosts... is that too idealistic of me?

Answer (score 0):

I have given Terry the accepted answer because that suggestion worked, and I believe will help most people.

However in my case I believe the culprit was some combination of skype, pending windows updates, and my preference to hibernate my PC rather than shutting down. I have had various networking issues since, and all of them have been solved by disabling skype from autoloading, and installing any windows updates pending at the time I have the error and restarting!

Even if I haven't used skype in days it still seems to gum up my system in between restarts / proper shutdowns.

Not the most high brow contribution to a Stack Exchange site ever, and dangerously close to superstition, but I am convinced of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an off the wall answer. Check your DHCP server for another machine taking that IP address before your vagrant box. You may actually be connecting to some friend's phone or laptop instead.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after using `auto_correct: true`. Just follow the tutorial in Hashicorp docs

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567,
    auto_correct: true
```